# Authentication: OpenStack w/ Charms Setup

Tags: juju, openstack

I installed https://jujucharms.com/u/openstack-charmers on a Google cloud instance. Can't login.

Setup an API key on Google which is in /etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings.py

The only username created seems to be 'ubuntu'? I can get to command line for the ubuntu user and to the Horizon console.

What am I missing to configure & login to the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Actually found this document the best config overview:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure

Maybe should be added to the readme